# How to read this JSON on Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, serialization

I have to read this JSON :

```
[   
    {"id":"2","code":"jne","name":"JNE"},   
    {"id":"5","code":"pcp","name":"PCP"},   
    {"id":"1","code":"pos","name":"Pos Indonesia"}, 
    {"id":"6","code":"wahana","name":"Wahana"}  
]
```

I have tried this :

```
[DataContract]
public class Ekspedisi
{
    [DataMember]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String code { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String name { get; set; }
}
```

and this:

```
public static Ekspedisi[] res;  
string link5 = "http://www.ongkoskirim.com/api/0.2/?id=OAL66afd139a386fee6dc5a5597abd7daba&q=expedition"    
WebClient client = new WebClient(); 
client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(client_OpenReadCompleted);    
client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(link5), UriKind.Absolute);
```

and this :

```
void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Ekspedisi));
        res = (Ekspedisi[])ser.ReadObject(e.Result);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(res[i].id+","+res[i].name); 
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

But it always showing `invalidCastException`. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are deserialising the JSON, you are using the type of Ekspedisi even though you are returning a collection. If you change this line of code:

```
var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Ekspedisi));
```

to

```
var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(IEnumerable<Ekspedisi>));
```

which is a collection of your type; you will find you no longer receive the exception.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very helping, I am no longer receive the Exception :)